# Secure key for android database

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

Is there any algorithm to generate an encrypted key in android to secure a database?

I tried this PBE algorithm:

```
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 
    NUM_OF_ITERATIONS, KEY_SIZE);
SecretKeyFactory factoryKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM);
SecretKey tempKey = factoryKey.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tempKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

But it generates the same key every time. Any other good algorithms for generating a secure key?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The code you've posted is *designed* to generate the same key each time the same password is used. Can you please explain in more detail what you want to do and we can maybe help. Are you needing to derive a key from a user password? Why would you want a different key each time?

Comment: I want an algorithm which generate every time new key

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random secret key, use the [KeyGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html) class, with code something like this:

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(KEY_SIZE);
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
```

Note that you will obviously have to store this key securely somewhere if you wish to decrypt your database later, hence it may be worthwhile to pursue the PBE-based solution proposed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically to achieve what you want you use your PBE key to encrypt/decrypt a random key (that you must store, keep it separate from your data as best you can) which you use to encrypt/decrypt your data. Then your data ciphertext, by itself, has no direct relation to your password without the encrypted keys.